# Angular: form validation - matched password doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I am simply creating the registration form with some basic validations

My code:

registration.html

```
<form #registrationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    ...

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reg_password">Pawword</label>
        <input required type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_password" name="reg_password" [(ngModel)]="register_inputs.password"
         #passwordControl="ngModel">

        <ng-container *ngIf="passwordControl.invalid && passwordControl.touched">
            <p class="error-message" *ngIf="passwordControl.errors?.required">
                Password is required!
            </p>
        </ng-container>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reg_r_password">Retype Password</label>
        <input required type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_r_password" name="reg_r_password" [(ngModel)]="register_inputs.r_password"
         #rPasswordControl="ngModel">

        <ng-container *ngIf="rPasswordControl.invalid && rPasswordControl.touched">
            <p class="error-message" *ngIf="rPasswordControl.errors?.required">
                Password confirmation is required!
            </p>
            <p class="error-message" *ngIf="(passwordControl.value != rPasswordControl.value) && !rPasswordControl.errors?.required">
                Password does not match the confirm password.
            </p>
        </ng-container>

    </div>

    ...

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center align-self-center">
            <button [disabled]="registrationForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

All validations are working, except the matched password validation.

Did I make something wrong?

Comment: you need to create async validator for password matching case.

Comment: can you make it more detail? Sorry, I am new with this.

Comment: check this: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/how-to-implement-custom-validator-confirm-password-in-angular2-rc-3-622288ba809d

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 2nd validation condition.

```
<p class="error-message" *ngIf="(passwordControl.value != rPasswordControl.value) && !rPasswordControl.errors?.required">
                Password does not match the confirm password.
            </p>
```

change it to

```
<p class="error-message" *ngIf="passwordControl.value != rPasswordControl.value">
                Password does not match the confirm password.
            </p>
```

On the submit button, you should add a condition because match password is not core validation. i.e;

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center align-self-center">
            <button [disabled]="passwordControl.value == rPasswordControl.value && registrationForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try using model variables for conditions i.e. 

**register_inputs.password != register_inputs.r_password**

OR you can do it in your component.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly how to archieve it with template driven forms but with reactive forms have this solution:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      name:                   ['', Validators.required ],
      password: this.fb.group({
        pw1:           ['', Validators.required ],
        pw2:          ['', Validators.required ],
      }, {validator: this.matchValidator}),
    })

  private matchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
    return g.get('pw1').value == g.get('pw2').value
    ? null : {'mismatch': true};
  }
```

More on reactive forms on here:
[angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this npm package that provides this exact feature for template-driven form fields

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-validate-equal

### Installation and Usage

#### Step #1:

install ng-validate-equal package

```sh
 npm i ng-validate-equal
```

#### Step #2:

import "ValidateEqualModule" in your module.ts and add it to the NgModule imports' array

```
import { ValidateEqualModule } from 'ng-validate-equal';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ValidateEqualModule
  ],
  providers: [],
})
```

#### Step #3:

- Make sure you surround your field and its confirmation/retype field in a  `<form> </form>`  tag
- Give your primary field a name
- Use the directive on the secondary field and pass the primary field's name to the directive
- Look for "notEqual" error in the confirmation field errors array

```html
<!-- form -->
<form>

<!-- password -->
<label>
  Password
</label>

<input type="password" name="passwordFieldName" placeholder="Password" #modelPassword="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.password">

<!-- confirm Password -->
<label>
  Confirm Password
</label>

<input type="password" ngValidateEqual="passwordFieldName" #modelConfirmPassword="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">

<div *ngIf="(modelConfirmPassword.dirty || modelConfirmPassword.touched) && modelConfirmPassword.invalid">
    <p class="warning-text" *ngIf="modelConfirmPassword.hasError('notEqual') && modelPassword.valid">
      Passwords Don't Match
    </p>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please include a few examples that illustrate, how the functionality of that package can be used in the question askers situation